# How to Implement the moving average filter in time domain in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, homework

I have a sinusoidal **x(t) = sin(500*π*t)** signal  is corrupted by random noise. The corrupted signal is sampled with sampling frequency **fs = 5 kHz** and passed through a **5-point moving average filter** to reduce the noise. I have written the following MATLAB Code for the same:-

```
fs=5e3; t=0:1/fs:0.02;
x=sin(2*pi*250*t);           % uncorrupted signal

r=0.1*randn(1,length(x));    % random noise
XR=x+r;                      % signal + noise (filter input)

y=0;
% Implement the moving average filter in time domain
for n=5:length(XR),          % M = 5   
    y(n) =                   % missing code using the command 'sum'
end

figure(12);
subplot(211); plot(t,XR,t,x,'r'); legend('Corrupted','Original');
xlabel('time (sec)'); ylabel('Amplitude'); grid;

subplot(212); plot(t,y,'k',t,x,'r'); legend('After filtering','Original'); 
xlabel('time (sec)'); ylabel('Amplitude');grid;
```

But, I am not sure **how to implement the moving average filter in time domain** using **sum command** to get the output **(y[n])** in the **for loop** as mentioned above in the code. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Is that homework? Than please tag it as that

Comment: I like how you have all the code, including the `subplot()` & co, but you don't have that particular line.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yeah cause that's an assignment question I got, and I am not asking the answer just for some suggestions/hints:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT (really an answer but not providing code so its a hint):

In your setup, a $M$-point moving average filter uses the average of the previous $M-1$ samples and the current sample to compute the current output. So for $n=5$, the output will be $\frac{1}{5}(x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5])$. In general, for $n=k$ the output of this $M$-point MA filter is:

$$ \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=k-M+1}^kx[k]$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1):

A 5-point moving average can be performed in different ways. The two principal options  consist in:

1. causal: take the current point, and average it with the four most recent past samples, or sum it and divide by the length of the average span (which seems to be your choiice, regarding your `for` bounds
   $$ y[n] = \left(\sum^n_{k=n-4} x[k]\right)/5\,,$$
2. symmetric: take the current point, and average it with two samples of the left and two on the right
   $$ y[n] = \left(\sum^{n+2}_{k=n-2} x[k]\right)/5\,.$$

You can find the most classical Matlab solutions by yourself, using for instance [Calculate moving average manually](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/609896-calculate-moving-average-manually). A last option could be more recursive, and implementable (with proper initialization) as:

```
z(n) =  sum([z(n-1),XR(n)/5-XR(n-5)/5]);
```

which might be your next exercise.